# Bootstrap - move the next <div> on top of previous on medium and small devices

Tags: html, css

I have the following `div` in `Bootstrap`:

```
<div class="card-header py-md-0 py-lg-0 py-xl-0 pl-0 pr-0">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="h5 mb-0">Text text</div>
        <div class="text-right">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="action-item"><i
                        class="far fa-heart mr-1"></i>
                    50</a>
                <a href="#" class="action-item"><i class="far fa-eye mr-1"></i>
                    250</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="font-size-1">Text text text text text
    </p>
</div>
```

On medium and small devices I would like that the second `div` having `class="actions"` to go on top of the first and aligned left.

I have tried so far to do something like below but it doesn't work. Something I'm missing:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .col-xs-12 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

Some tips? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap 4:

Bootstrap is built for mobile-first, so the easiest solution is to layout the code in order from the `.sm` view, which would be the `div` you want first as the first one in that entire `.row`.

Here is the section in Bootstrap 4 covering this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#order-classes

You'll have to add `.order-lg-2` to the `div` you want to show first on `sm` and `md` screens (remember, mobile first). You can also use things Bootstrap classes like `.justify-content-[sm, md, lg]-[start, center, between, end, around]` to set its position. You may also have to add `.d-flex` to the second `div` (that's how it all worked for me in a project).

Here is an example of what I've used that worked (these sections were side-by-side on `lg+`, so your column sizes might need to be adjusted):

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 order-lg-2 justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start"> <!-- shows first on sm/md, 2nd on lg -->
           <!-- your code -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 order-lg-1 justify-content-center justify-content-md-start"> <!-- shows 2nd on sm/md, 1st on lg -->
          <!-- more code -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a quick CodePen I set up to show you how it works:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeffberlin/pen/mdeMqKP?editors=1100)

Comment: Hi Jeff! I understand your answer but it's not what I wanted. This basically changes the orders of displaying the element. However, I wanted that the 2nd `div` to be displayed above of the 1st `div` starting medium devices.

Comment: Per Bootstrap, you should oder from smallest to biggest screen, so your code layout SHOULD be in order of how it would naturally display on the smaller screens and then add the classes (`order-*-*`) to set them where you want them as the screen expands at the breakpoints. Bootstrap will automatically handle reordering them based on the `.order-lg-*` at that breakpoint and above.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a CodePen example for you of how it works.